# jQuery get position of element based on parents width. .position()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following fiddle you can see where i am trying to get the position left of a child element based on the parent so that i can place a marker there. But all of the results of `$this.position().left;` is always more than it should be.

How would you modify the fiddle to make `.line` move to the hovered element?

https://jsfiddle.net/57d0cw46/27/

## html

```
<ul class="inline pricing-list">
    <div class="line">|</div>
    <li>
        <a data-index="1">
            <div class="qty">48</div>         
            <div class="price">$15</div>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a data-index="2">
            <div class="qty">60</div>      
            <div class="price">$13</div>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a data-index="3">
            <div class="qty">120</div>
            <div class="price">$11.5</div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## js

```
const $trigger = $('[data-index]');
const $line = $('.line');
$trigger.hover( function() {
    const place = $(this).position().left;
    $line.css('margin-left',place+'%');
});
```

Comment: Switch the last line to px? `$line.css('margin-left',place+'px');`

Comment: dang yes. Thought it was something more serious